# Where can I find the source code for javap application?

Tags: java, jvm, disassembly, decompiler, javap

[javap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javap.html) is the Java Class File Disassembler.
Which, in my system, is an application that belongs to Oracle JDK.

```
$ javap -version
1.8.0_201

$ which javap
/opt/jdk1.8.0_201/bin/javap

$ head -2 /opt/jdk1.8.0_201/COPYRIGHT
Copyright � 1993, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
All rights reserved.
```

I would like to know the internals of how `javap` works.
That would show JVM internals by example, and how to disassemble class files.

Can I get the source code for `javap` application somewhere?
Since it belongs to Oracle, I would say no... but...

Is there a similar tool made by OpenJDK developers?

Comment: [`sun.tools.javap`](https://github.com/kohsuke/javap/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/javap)

Comment: Also it is also part of the OpenJDK codebase that you can access here: https://openjdk.java.net/.  *"Is there a similar tool made by OpenJDK developers?"*   It is the same tool.  Same source code.

Answer (score 1):

As Elliot commented you can find it on Github, however the link in the comment is a mirror from 5 years ago. You can find an updated repository here:

- [com.sun.tools.javap](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javap)
- [com.sun.tools.classfile](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/classfile)

[OpenJDK migrated to GitHub a while ago.](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/07/openjdk-github-migration/)

Comment: 2022 update: you can find OpenJDK's current sources for javap [here on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javap). Same goes for [com.sun.tools.classfile](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jdeps/share/classes/com/sun/tools/classfile).

Comment: Good note, updated the answer

Comment: Just one thing, I think you can remove the mirror mention - seems like OpenJDK has actually moved to GitHub as the mainline.